# Remove more than two consecutive occurrence

Tags: java

I have  a java `String` like this

```
String str="&P;&P;&P;&P;&P;&P;&P;&P;&P;&P;&P;&P; Tannay Mnadal &P;&P;&P;&P;&P;&P; Tata"
```

I am trying to remove all `&P;` where the consecutive occurrence is more than  two.

ie. any `function(str)` , will return `"&P;&P;"  Tannay Mnadal &P;&P; Tata`

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll("&P;&P;(&P;)+", "&P;&P;");
```

Comment: @jzd: ya my whole network went down after I posted that.  Just fixed it from my smartphone.  I like the range operator better though.

Comment: @jzd: Actually it met the requirement of three or more (he said "more than two"), but @Tanmay said he wanted to remove **all** `&P;` where there's two or more, and that's what I originally gave.  But his example indicates he wants to remove **all but two** `&P;`.

Comment: yes, I see now that his requirement does not match his example.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression with `replaceAll()`

Something like:

```
str.replaceAll("(&P;){3,}", "&P;&P;");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a regex replace:

```
public String function(String str)
{
    return str.replaceAll("&P;&P;(&P;)+", "&P;&P;");
    // I understood you wanted to keep two times "&P;"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with regular expressions easily:

```
public String removeOcurrences(String input) {

    return input.replaceAll("(&P;&P;)(?:&P;)*", "$1");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.